# Rails asset pipeline returning 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I'm at my wits end! I've inherited a rails application - the previous developer decided not to use the asset pipeline and basically deleted all the config options. I'm trying to put it back in.

System is as follows:

- Rails 3.2.18 hosted at https://example.com/-/
- thin + apache (NOT heroku)
- It's mid migration from rails 2 to rails 3.2.18, so the old version is at example.com and the new version is at example.com/-/ - done using apache rewrite rule.

*** Problem ***

The asset pipeline is returning 404 for application.js and application.css.

*** Setup ***

app/assets folders all set up as per a basic rails 3 installation.

** Gemfile **

```
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
```

**layout file**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag     "application", media: 'all' %>                                                                                                              
<%= javascript_include_tag  "application" %>
```

**application.rb** asset related options

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'    
config.assets.serve_static_assets = true

config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new do |source, request|
  "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}/-"
end
```

**environments/development.rb** asset related options

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

**environments/production.rb** asset related options

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

And I am compiling with rake assets:precompile, which succesfully creates the assets folder under public/assets. I put a line of test script into application.css and application.js under app/assets, and can see that it is those files that end up in public/assets.

So, all would appear to be compiling properly... but the requests aren't working!

*** Problem ***

In development mode the above is rendering:

```
  <link href="https://example.com/-/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://example.com/-/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In production it renders:

```
<link href="https://example.com/-/assets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://example.com/-/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All of which come back with 404.

**Also**: If I put other files in the assets folder, they get served! For example, I added the file foo.txt to the public/assets folder alongside the compiled assets, then browsed to

```
https://example.com/-/assets/foo.txt
```

and it worked just fine. I change foo.txt to application.css;

```
https://example.com/-/assets/application.css
```

and it 404s, even though I can see the file is in the folder - I've googled the hell out of this and all signs point to that "serve_static_assets" option, but as you can see I've got it set to true (plus, I'm running through apache so allegedly shouldn't have to set it to true at all).

If anyone knows what's going on here I'd really appreciate it!

**Why would rails behave differently with its requests for different types of file?!**

Comment: in production, are the assets configured to be served by apache or thin? If by apache (usually preferred in production), is there anything useful in the apache logs, for getting a 404 for application.css versus getting a 200 for foo.txt (using your example paths)? Also, you might want to leave the asset pipeline out until the rest of the migration to rails 3.2.x is done, and then configure it. Separating the steps seemed easier on an app I migrated from 3.0.x to 3.2.x.

Comment: Our environment is a little odd - our development and production environments are the same environment (we sell physical appliances with the software pre-installed on it) - so we're using apache both in development AND in production.

Nowt interesting in apache logs.

Totally taking on board your comments about leaving this until migration is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorted - some muppet had added in an apache rewrite rule to ensure all css/js files (regex) go to some folder on the other end of the hard drive.

Comment: Can't tell if you're a robot or not - totally plan on accepting this answer as soon as I can - right now I can't because it's an answer to my own question and there's a time limit before you can accept!